# A way to raise or lower terrain?

Tags: simcity-2013

I'm trying to build a ferry terminal along my coast. However, when i place a ferry building along the cost, the access road is too steep of an incline and I can't build a connecting road to complete my road circuit.

Is there a way to raise or lower terrain to smooth out the terrain enough for me to build a connecting road?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.  There are no terraforming tools in the game.

If the game will not change the terrain enough for you to place your road or building, you'll have to shift it over in small increments until you find an acceptable location.

Comment: Not even by placing some other building that raises or lowers the terrain? In some games you can do this, then demolish the building that modified the terrain and the terrain becomes permanently modified.

Comment: You can place roads and buildings along a slope and while in place, will alter the terrain a bit to support it.  But the moment you remove that road/building, the terrain will revert back to how it was.